# get string from class to class

Tags: java

i have class m1
that have inside it
new m2().execute();
        new m3().execute();

so

```
public class m1 extends Activity {

new m2().execute();
        new m3().execute();
 class m2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 public void s {


                         String  id3 = map12.get("CourseID");
}
}
 class m3 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
}//m3
}//m
```

how can i get the id3 to class m3 ? knowing it is change eachthime

Comment: you can define it under m1 class so it its accessible to everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make id3 public static in this class m1 and then access it diretly in class m3 like m1.id3.

```
     public class m1 extends Activity {
       public static String id3;
        //your code
          }


     public class m3 {
       m1 Object1=new m1();  //make object of class m1
       Object1.id3;  // You can access id3 in class m3
        //your code
          }
```

Comment: i do as you said there is a problem can not access it

Comment: So, just make an object of class m1 in class m3  and then access id3 using that object (keep id3 public static in class m1)

Comment: with you code i can get the value of id3 that is inside m2 in method s

Comment: You must declare it outside method of m2

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as part of your constructor, and pass it along when you instantiate it (assuming you're calling it from `m1`.

```
private String id3;

public m3(String theId3) {
    id3 = theId3;
}
```

Comment: but my method is different parameter how can i change it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.  What I've done here was add the `String` to the instance level of `m3`; you can then use that variable as you wish inside of `m3`.

Comment: i should have the m3 like this lass m3 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> how can i add the id3 also with it